# Comment generator

Tags: javascript, automation, generator

I am looking for a script that can automatically generate comments or a summarised description based on various inputs made in previous steps of a form.

I have seen this functionality enabled on an Australian car advertisements web site http://carsales.com.au

I have a screen capture of the page below (you need to be registered to access the page and have filled out the previous steps of the form):

[image]

The way this seems to work is that the user has previously entered a large amount of information regarding the car they want to sell in the previous 3 to 4 pages of the ad submission form. On this page, they are then presented with a text area where they can write a more detailed description of the car.

They are also given the opportunity to click on the blue **Enhance Comments** button, and automagically, a rather detailed description or comment is input in the text area for the user.

Unfortunately, I have no further details about how this function works, but I am assuming that clicking on the button triggers a javascript which then generates a detailed description by pulling in the data previously entered and formatting it in some template-based structure.

Can anyone advise as to the script that is being used, or a similar functionality that can be implemented?

Thanks